# WSS 3.0 Site People and Groups

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0

When people are added to a WSS site, their title and department are imported from Active Directory. As time goes on, titles and departments can change. Is there a way to get this information updated in the WSS site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script from CodeProject should do what you're looking for or at least point you in the right direction

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/SPUpdateUserInfoList.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I work on SharePoint at Microsoft

In WSS I'm not aware of a way to do this without custom code. I haven't checked out the script in Kevin Kuphal's response to vouch for it. The (for-pay) MOSS (Microsoft Office SharePoint Server..) comes with a user profile sync timer job that attempts to solve this.